# CKeditor image toolbar without upload

Tags: ckeditor5

CKeditor5 by default has image plugins that support toolbar icons which can insert an image by (a) uploading the image and (b) insert an IMG tag into the HTML.

We do not want any capability to upload an image, but we need a simple widget that takes user input and inserts an image tag with attributes (user supplied) including e.g. SRC, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CLASS.

Seems strange that this isn't available in the standard build, have I missed it somehow?

Do we have to write our own plugin?

Answer (score -2):

Custom build your CKeditor here:
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

Use toolbar item            'imageInsert'

relevant plugins:

```
Image,
ImageCaption, // adds ability to caption image via the toolbar
ImageInsert,
ImageResize, // this will cause resize handles to appear in the editor, operates by applying CSS to the enclosing <figure> tag
```

Also useful plugin

```
LinkImage,  // adds link capability when editing an inserted image
```

Found the relevant doc here
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/images-inserting.html

Comment: Nik Dow, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Added more helpful instructions